# Pseudo-classical vs. Surrogate Function Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between the following two ways of implementing class inheritance in JavaScript?

```
function Super () {
}

function Sub() {
}
Sub.prototype = new Super();
```

vs.

```
Function.prototype.inherits = function inherits(ParentClass) {
    function Surrogate () {};
    Surrogate.prototype = ParentClass.prototype;
    this.prototype = new Surrogate();
}
```

Specifically, for the second example using a surrogate function, why can't we just use:

```
Function.prototype.inherits = function inherits(ParentClass) {
    this.prototype = new ParentClass();
}
```

I thought that by calling `new` on the `ParentClass()` and setting it to `this.prototype`, the `this.prototype` then points to `ParentClass.prototype`, hence inheriting from the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, for the second example using a surrogate function, why can't we just use [...]

The `Surrogate` way is basically a shim for [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), the modern practice is

```
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Super.prototype);
```

and if you need to invoke the constructor of *Super* on your instance,

```
function Sub() {
    // an instanceof check here
    Super.apply(this);
    // construct Sub as desired
}
```

---

The advantage of not having an instance of *Super* as the prototype of *Sub* is that we have better control over instances of *Sub* and don't have weird bugs resulting from unexpected shared values,

Consider the following

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = [];
}

function Fizz() {}
Fizz.prototype = new Foo();

var a = new Fizz(),
    b = new Fizz();
a.bar.push('Hello world!');
// What is b.bar?
b.bar; // ["Hello world!"], we are sharing with `a`
```

vs

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = [];
}

function Fizz() {
    Foo.apply(this);
}
Fizz.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

var a = new Fizz(),
    b = new Fizz();
a.bar.push('Hello world!');
// What is b.bar?
b.bar; // [], `b` has some privacy at last
```

Comment: How come `Sub.prototype = new Super()` works for the first block of code above, whereas we can't just use `this.prototype = new ParentClass()` in the third block of code above? Are those ways correct?

Comment: @fibono The point is to have an empty _Object_ that inherits `ParentClass.prototype` without having an instance of _ParentClass_ in the prototype chain

Comment: I've never thought about it that way. It seems like what's happening (at least in my mind) is that when you set the `subObject.prototype` to `new Super()`, there is another "link" if you will on the prototype chain (the `new Super()` object). On the other hand, using `Object.create` or a surrogate function basically makes the chain like: `subObject --> subObject.prototype --> superClass.prototype`.